# How to solve this derivative question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am in a bit over my head with a math course I joined voluntarily. This is the first question. I am learning but not as fast as it seems.

Q: If $f:(-{\displaystyle \pi }/6,{\displaystyle \pi }/6) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is defined by $f(x)=2^x\tan(3x)$ for every $x {\displaystyle \in } (-{\displaystyle \pi }/6,{\displaystyle \pi }/6)$, then $f'(0)$ will be equal to (a) $\ln 2$ (b) $0$ (c) $2{\displaystyle \pi }$ (d) $3$

I want to know how to solve this, and what the chapter this is from and whats the exact resource that can help me learn this. I have figured this is linear approximation. Is that right ?

(And Boy, I just learned Latex, that was so much fun :)

Comment: "I have figured this is linear approximation. Is that right ?"  No.  Just actually figure out the actual derivative and plug in $x=0$.  It's a real kitchen sink derivative but if you use the product and chain rule it's straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forgot to edit that line. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just rules of derivatives, like [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule);

evaluate $f'(x)=\ln2\cdot2^x\tan(3x)+2^x\sec^2(3x)\cdot3$ at $x=0$.

Comment: So the -/6,/6 hold no weight in this question ?

Comment: those are merely the endpoints of the interval that is the domain of the function (which includes $0$)

Comment: So basically the question is asking me to find derivative of the function and substitute x as 0 in the solution.

Comment: I think you've got it!

Comment: May I ask you for a step by step of this ? I am trying to follow the formulae. Just need to wrap my head around this. 

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(2^x\right)\tan \left(3x\right)+\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan \left(3x\right)\right)2^x$

Comment: $\dfrac d{dx} e^{\ln 2x}=\ln 2 e^{\ln 2x}$ and $\dfrac d{dx}\tan y=\sec^2 y\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ ; is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Got it!!!!!!!! $f'g +g'f$

Comment: Yes, that's the product rule

Comment: Thanks a lot @J. W. Tanner. This helped a lot. I will come back with more though. :)

Comment: You're welcome; you could click the up-arrow and/or check mark next to my answer to acknowledge that

Comment: Done. However due to low points i cannot up-vote that answer.

Comment: My up-vote is hidden. :(